# What vol to use when implying strike from delta?

Tags: options, delta, implied

I have a set of implied vols in delta space and want to derive for each delta the corresponding strike. I understand the procedure, but I am not sure what implied vol I should use, whether this has to be the ATM vol or the vol for the fitted vol for that specific delta.

Thanks!

Comment: each market has specific rules. See for instance http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/FX/FX%20Volatility.pdf for an overview of the FX market.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is vol for specific delta.You can use ATM vol to back out ATM strike. Because Vols of strikes on the same expiry is a smile(smirk), not a flat line, you have to use different vols to back out corresponding strikes based on delta and other given option variables(underlying price, vol, t, r, q).